# kinetic js textPath: draggable didn't work

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

```js
var stages = new Array() ;
   var limites = new Array() ;
   numStage=0;
   r = {
   'x':65,
   'y':120,
   'xwidth':335,
   'yheight':210
   };
   limites.push(r);
   
   stages[numStage] = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'cmg_canvas_'+numStage,
    width: 450,
    height: 450
   });
   //creation image
   obj = new Image();
   obj.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/zFZgKuS.jpg';
   image = new Kinetic.Image({
    image: obj,
    width: 450,
    height: 450
   });
   // add image to calque
   layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
   layer.add(image);
   stages[numStage].add(layer); //add image to canvas
      
   layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
   //set limit x y h l
   /*var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    name: 'limite',
    x: limites[numStage].x,
    y: limites[numStage].y,
    width: limites[numStage].xwidth,
    height: limites[numStage].yheight,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0.5
   });*/
   //layer.add(rect);// add to canvas
   stages[numStage].add(layer);
   
   $('.cmg_text').live('blur', function(){
    
    idText = 'cmg_line0'; 
    
    numStage = 0;
    
    drawTextPath(numStage, idText,$(this).val(),50,22,numStage);
    //text = getText(this).text;
      
   });
   
   
   function getSVG(x,y,w,verif) {
     halfw = parseFloat((w/2).toFixed(2));
     x1 = parseFloat((halfw/2).toFixed(2));
     x2 = parseFloat(halfw + x1);
     
     if(parseInt(verif))
     {
      y1 = parseFloat(y) * 2 +18;
      y2 = parseFloat(y) * 2 +18;
     }
     else
     {
      y1 = -18;
      y2 = -18; 
     }
     
     str = 'M '+x+','+y+' C '+x1+','+y1+' '+x2+','+y2+' '+w+','+y;
     return str;
    }
   
   function drawTextPath(numStage, textId,text,valueSlider, newFontSize,numStage){
     //'M 0,115 C42,-18 126,-18 165,115';
     //'M 0,115 C45,230 180,230 180,115';
     var arcOnly = 0;
     if(textId == 'cmg_line0')
     {
       console.log('limites[numStage].yheight/2'+limites[numStage].yheight/2);
       console.log('limites[numStage].xwidth'+limites[numStage].xwidth);
      svg  = getSVG(0,valueSlider,valueSlider*6.3,0);
      arcOnly = 0;
     }
    //alert(svg);
     console.log(parseFloat(limites[numStage].y)); 
     console.log(parseFloat(arcOnly)); 
     console.log(parseFloat(limites[numStage].y - arcOnly)); 
      
     var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({name:'textPathLayer',draggable:true});
     var textpath = new Kinetic.TextPath({
      name:'TextPath',
      id: textId,
      //x: 0,
      //x: limites[numStage].x + limites[numStage].xwidth/2,
      //y: 0,
      //y: limites[numStage].y + limites[numStage].yheight/2,
      x: limites[numStage].x ,
      y: limites[numStage].y + limites[numStage].yheight/2,
      fill: '#000',
      fontSize: newFontSize,
      fontFamily: 'Arial',
      text: text,
      //offsetX:0,
      //offsetY:0,
      draggable: true,
      dragBoundFunc: function(pos){
       p = textParams(this, pos);
       return {x: p.newX, y: p.newY};
       },
       
      data: svg
     });
      
      //
     layer.add(textpath);
       
     stages[numStage].add(layer);
      //layer.moveToTop();
     //layer.draw();
      //stages[0].draw();
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/4.6.0/kinetic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cmg_canvas_0"></div>
   <input type='text' class='cmg_text' />
```

I have to draw a draggable textpath with kineticjs, with text given by an input text, the action is triggered in blur.
I have a stage that contain 3 layers;
Layer for the background, and one layer for the textpath.
My problem that the draggable in the textpath is not working,
i tried to set the text layer in the top, but i didn't get it draggable.

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bc7s9f8/)
I have a doubt of inner layer problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think hit detection works properly on TextPaths. At least, I can only get it to work if there is an object behind the TextPath object that _does_ report hit detection. And even then it is as if clicking anywhere initiates dragging for the TextPath object.

Comment: thank you for your response, can you share with us your working solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0bc7s9f8/3/ I wouldn't call it a solution, though.

Comment: Thank you, but still have confusion, why my code is not working, i used multiple layers, is it the problem?  you can clarify your solution and i will accept it as a valid answer

Comment: Using multiple layers isn't the issue (I just used one layer for the sake of simplicity in debugging). As I mentioned earlier, hit detection is not being reported for the TextPath. To get dragging to start we rely on the objects behind the TextPath that _do_ report hit detection. Technically, creating a group that is draggable with a Rect and TextPath as its children is a possible work around (and solution), but difficulty may be found in obtaining width and height of the TextPath to reshape the Rect with.

Comment: i want only the text, to be draggable, the rectangle is created to set limits, a group is not fit my requirement

Comment: I meant, when you create a new TextPath to also create a Rect and a Group, and add the TextPath and Rect to the group. A group will not fire mouse events without a child that can report hit detection. We would use this Rect to cover the area that the TextPath would take up. Only thing left to do is to calculate width and height for the Rect.